# how to convert RDBMS monolithic database into microservice architecture based database

Tags: microservices

I am planning to convert tightly coupled RDBMS monothetic database into microservice architecture database so what i am trying to do :-
1-  Oracle database server we are using.
2-  In existing Oracle database, There is only one schema which serve the whole application functionality.
3-  We are splitting our RDBMS on the basis of business functionality.
4-  We are creating 4 to 5 schemas on the basis of business functionality and splitting existing database objects on the basis of business functionality into these newly created 4 to 5 schemas.
5-  Now we are facing some issues that there are some tables or materialized views which are overlapping in two or more than two schemas.
6- So objects which are overlapping two or more than two schemas, we are trying to create common schema and putting tables and materialized views into this newly created common schema then we will provide the grants of there common objects to required schemas.
7- there is one more schema required for reporting so what we are doing that we are again creating new reporting schema and in this schema all tables of database are being used so we are providing grants of all tables to this reporting schema from all other schema.

Now my question is that does above exercise follow the microservice architecture because on realistic lines we can draw this or is there any other way to design existing application database into micro service based database?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puh0d.jpg)

Comment: I recommend you read https://stackoverflow.com/a/54688776/1235935 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/54676222/1235935 and

Answer (score 0):

You are doing some part correct; while some part wrong. It is a given, that in micro-services architecture some data will be duplicated at multiple places(in different schemas); and this is one the disadvantage of micro-service.. Biggest challenge is to make sure that data is in sync in all the schemas.

If you try to keep data only in one place; you will end up in lots of API calls between the services.